# Non-renewable resources metallic recycling

Tags: energy-economics

Why, in the presence of recycling capability, are metallic non-renewable resources eventually exhaustible?

Comment: Hi! The question is a little difficult to understand. are you asking what is the purpose for recycling metals?

Comment: I wanted to know why in the presence of recycling ultimately metallic non-renewable resources get eventually exhaustible .

Comment: People don't bother to recycle?